# What does HTTP look like?

Tags: http, terminology

I've been working a lot with HTTP related things - HTTP requests, HTTP responses, HTTP methods etc., but I'm not really sure I understand what the protocol itself looks like. Is it a document like a specification?

Comment: Installing and playing with a realtime HTTP debugger can be illuminating; (win) http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: How about Googling "HTTP Protocol"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it a document like a specification?

Yes, HTTP is a protocol over TCP/IP defined in the following specification: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html

This protocol is for example implemented by web servers and client browsers.

Comment: Cool, but then why is not called "specification"?

Comment: @Emanuil Rusev, because it is a protocol. Every protocol is a specification defined somewhere otherwise it wouldn't be standard.

Comment: @Darin, would it be correct then to call a technical specification of a project a protocol?

Comment: @Emanuil Rusev, absolutely not. It would depend on the project. If the purpose of this project is to define a new protocol then yes its specification or as it is called RFC (Request For Comments) would be this protocol specification.

Answer (score 10):

Hyper Text Transfer Protocol (HTTP) provides a pattern to interact with Resources (e.g. webpages on a webserver). Essentially it boils down to a Request (typically from a browser) and a Response (typically from a webserver).

[image: HTTP visualization]

The request highlighted red above identifies an action verb such as GET, POST, DELETE, or PUT (there are [others verbs too](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Verbs#Request_methods)) and a resource (URI/URL) to preform the action on. The request above depicts a browser request to view the wikipedia main page.

The server then responds to the request with the blue and green sections above; they represent the response header and the response body. The response header contains a lot of optional information about the server but the important fields are the status code (200 OK), the content length (54218) and the content type (text/html).

Since the content type is html the browser will try to render the html inside the response body. If the content type were something else such as a word doc then the browser would probably open a save dialog box. There are a [plethora of content types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type#List_of_common_media_types) that the body could represent, but not all browsers support each of the content types.

Comment: See http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c6/Http_request_telnet_ubuntu.png for a zoomed up image of the screenshot.

Comment: This answer looms high above the accepted answer and should be noted as the archetype of a real answer on Stack Overflow. Thanks, Darwyn